# python csv reader scientific notations

Tags: python

```
import csv
excel_cell = 6.48084E+11
cell = csv.reader(excel_cell)
print cell
>> cell = 6.48084E+11
# My desired output would be cell = 648084201003
```

I am trying to use the csv reader in python to read an excel csv and return some of the values.  The cell displays in scientific notations but if I click on the cell, it shows its value is `648084201003`. Is there a way I can read this as digits rather than scientific notation?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you post an example line of the CSV file and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv.reader is completely unrelated to the problem.  It returns rows of the items:

```
>>> a = 6.48084E+11
>>> a
648084000000.0
>>> s = '{0:.0f}'.format(a)
>>> s
'648084000000'
>>> print s
648084000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
>>> l = 6.48084E+11
>>> print l
6.48084e+11
>>> print repr(l)
648084000000.0
```